# Why did Apple assign the wrong name to my AppleID, and how do I change it?

Tags: ipad, icloud, apple-id

I'm setting up an iPad for Mom's birthday. In the process, I created her an AppleID, and typed in her name. Signing into iCloud using her ID shows my name instead.  How do I fix this?

Comment: If you properly followed [Create and start using an Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203993), using only information pertaining to her, and not you in any way, there shouldn't be an issue. I'd contact Apple directly to resolve it.

Comment: I've had this issue as well, though the cause may be different. The card that I charge to doesn't have the same name as my Apple ID–sometimes it decides to use that as my name instead of the one I tied to my Apple ID.

Comment: It could also be something different,go to https://appleid.apple.com and see if everything is good.

Comment: Thank you, JMY1000. I did indeed put my card info for the time being. Is it safe to assume, then, that when I switch it to her card the name will change? Also, supposing it hadn't been that, how would you go about changing the name?

Answer (score 2):

If the name on the Apple ID or the billing address is incorrect, you can fix it at https://appleid.apple.com

You can edit the name on the account here...
[image: Edit Account]

And you can edit the billing name here...
[image: Edit Payment]

(Look for the **Edit** buttons.)

Comment: Neither of those is what I'm trying to change, but thanks.

Comment: I think they are. I’ve clarified the answer.